# Finding which files the migration assistant failed to transfer

Tags: data-synchronization, data-transfer, migration

I ran a transfer of about 4 TB of files from my failing Mac to my new Mac. After 62 hours of direct connection transfer time (which seems inexplicable), I was told at the very end of the process that not all files could be transferred without telling me which ones I may have still stuck on my old Mac.

Is there anyway I can get a list of the failed transfer files or do I have to start the entire process over and hope it doesn't fail a 2nd time over the 3 day span of time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare contents by setting the source computer to [Target Disk Mode](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/transfer-files-mac-computers-target-disk-mode-mchlp1443/mac), connecting both computers via cable or network, and compare contents using a tool like [Beyond Compare](https://scootersoftware.com/) (long free trial, more than enough for this job).

Comment: I just ended up copying everything to an external drive then replacing everything on the target Mac, but this would have been a good option as well. Completely forgot Beyond Compare can be used for more than just code merges. :)

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and execute:

```
diff -qr /Volumes/newharddrive /Volumes/oldharddrive
```

you have to change the names of the hard drives (or directories) according to your setup.

```
diff -qr /Volumes/newharddrive /Volumes/oldhardrive | grep ' differ'
```

is a variant to reduce the output clutter.

You can redirect the output from the terminal to a text file for easier reading:

```
diff -qr /Volumes/newharddrive /Volumes/oldhardrive >compare.txt
```

Comment: I'd like to add that this method using `diff` will take an excessively long time just to check if files *exist*, and not only that but it will actually **fail to detect existing files** as well, in the sense that it doesn't perform normalization of the filenames before comparing them. This means that a file "Namnlös" will be reported as missing just because APFS volume #1 did not represent "ö" the same way as APFS volume #2. This happened to me after using Migration Assistant followed by `diff -qr`.

Comment: `rsync --dry-run` can alleviate these problems and can turn a hour long process into a few seconds, in my experience.